# RSS feed doesn't validate

Tags: wordpress, rss

I get this error on my default [WordPress feed](http://goo.gl/V5zn1E): `pubDate must be an RFC-822 date-time: Mon, 30 Nov -0001 00:00:00 +0000`

Anything inherently evil in `pubDate`? And if so how to solve the problem?

Comment: http://feedvalidator.org/docs/error/InvalidRFC2822Date.html - see "solution" section

Comment: Thanks, it says: "Solution: Change the date-time format to comply with RFC822". But this is default feed generated by WordPress and in WordPress you can't change this kind of things, settings are pretty limited. Any suggestion?

Comment: You have `-0001 00:00:00 +0000` this is the only thing that is wrong. Try resetting your permalinks. The date at the front should be the year (2016 if it's from the current year).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the two occurrences of the error from Feed Validator, it's only happening because of the oldest two posts in the feed. Every post after that has the correct pubdate specification. WordPress itself follows the specification, but those two posts are missing the year.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897905/inserted-wordpress-post-shows-bad-date-in-rss-feed) might be of use, as it's what's occurring in your posts

> There are 4 dates stored for each WP post: Post_date, post_date_gmt,
> post_modified and post_modified_gmt. I recommend you to insert the
> same date for both post_date and post_modified and see if it works.
>
> That worked, thanks! It was just the post_date_gmt field that needed
> to be set.

If it's just those two, you can manually edit them in the wp_posts table in your database if you feel comfortable doing so, or there are various plugins available that can help with doing such a thing.

**PSA: Always have a backup of your database before fiddling with it.**

Answer (score 0):

Upgrage your plugins with newer version here https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/
because there is a bug
https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/issues/525

but if it has not been solve your problems, then better you remove this two post 
your.url/cliff-diving-boracay-philippines
your.url/bora-bora-activities-snorkeling-hibiscus

or make new version of those.

Answer (score -2):

Try this .. might work

Go into your wp-includes directory and edit the feed-rss2.php file.

Replace this (line no : 89):

```
<pubDate><?php echo mysql2date('D, d M Y H:i:s +0000', get_post_time('Y-m-d H:i:s', true), false); ?></pubDate>
```

With this:

```
<pubDate><?php echo mysql2date('r', get_the_time('Y-m-d H:i:s')); ?></pubDate>
```

And also try to update the Post for which the date is wrong : 
**post ID = 17624 and 17637** or see the published date of these posts in edit screen

[image]

Comment: The latter might work, but regarding the first suggestion, it's in general not recommended to edit core files.